# Azure monitor text log using azure monitor agent

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to set up log collection of a text based log file.
i'm able to retrieve the log file when nsgs are disabled, so my collection rules, tables and endpoints must be correct ( i think).

when activating nsg on the subnet where the vm (windows) is located, im allowing AzureMonitor and Storage servicetags both outbound and inbound (any port).
i do have a deny-all outbound rule.

i've tried to disable nsgs, this works, i'm guessing its the deny all outbound that is causing the issue, but i would expect the service tags with lower priority should supersede this rule. i would like to keep the deny all out rule.

Any tips?